# Cloud Foundry on Azure and Virtual machines

Tags: azure, cloud-foundry

We have planed to use PCF on Azure.

Does it means that we need to manage VMs on Azure ourself or it will be a PaaS on PaaS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Cloud Foundry on Azure will use our IaaS VMs.  There is no Cloud Foundry PaaS Service option in Azure.